# Rewrite only URLs that don't exist

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2

I'm looking for a way to rewrite URLs only if the path doesn't exist. This isn't to handle 404s, but to redirect page URLs to a shared PHP file `(ie: '/contact-us/' -> '/show_page.php?page=contact-us')`.

The basic redirect is easy enough to achieve, however I want to be able to override the default page by adding `/contact-us/index.php` in the site root.

Is this achievable with `mod_rewrite` or would I have to do something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check the value of the `REQUEST_FILENAME` variable:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ...
```

Comment: Aha, thank you. I haven't read too deeply into rewrite conditions yet, I've been mastering the rules and regexp.